# Python convert date string to datetime

Tags: python, datetime

Im trying to convert a date string into Python but get errors -

String: `'1986-09-22T00:00:00'`

```
dob_python = datetime.strptime('1986-09-22T00:00:00' , '%Y-%m-%d%Z%H-%M-%S').date()
```

Error:-

```
ValueError: time data '1986-09-22T00:00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d%Z%H-%M-%S'
```

Answer (score 8):

`T` is not a timezone. It is *just* a separator. Don't use `%Z` to try and parse it, use a literal `T`. Your time separators must match as well; you need to look for `:` colons, not dashes:

```
dob_python = datetime.strptime('1986-09-22T00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').date()
#                                                              ^  ^  ^
```

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('1986-09-22T00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').date()
datetime.date(1986, 9, 22)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) module greatly simplifies work when dealing with datetimes in python.

Using dateutil, you date could be formatted like this:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser as dateparser
>>> dob_python = dateparser.parse('1986-09-22T00:00:00')
>>> dob_python.date()
datetime.date(1986, 9, 22)
```

The parse function takes an optional parameter `parseinfo` for more complex or ambiguous string representations, but for the *standard-ish* date-string that you have, additional arguments are not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Notice your corresponding format string -- otherwise it will be error.

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('1986-09-22T01:02:03', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').date()
#datetime.date(1986, 9, 22)
```

`1986` matchs `%Y`

`09` matchs `%m`

`22` matchs `%d`

`01` matchs `%H`

`02` matchs `%M`

`03` matchs `%S`

In detail, you can refer python document. It has clear description and example.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 0):

You can use [easy_date](https://github.com/ralphavalon/easy_date) to make it easy:

```
import date_converter
dob_python = date_converter.string_to_date('1986-09-22T00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

Note: I am the author of the library

The library makes it easy because you only need to think about which type you want, e.g.: `string_to_date`, `date_to_datetime`, `string_to_timestamp` and so on...

Comment: This appears to be your library. The typical site courtesy is to provide a note to that effect, e.g. "note: I am the author of the library". It'd also be nice to see a few words about what this library does, and why it's preferable to using the native code provided in other answers. What's "easy" here exactly? Thanks.